# Динамическая корзина

Tags: html, css

Сверху страницы есть корзина, как сделать что бы она была `relative`, но если выходит из зоны видимости, отрывалась и становилась `fixed`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на событии скоролла проверяете если смещение больше высоты корзины = делать ее фиксед

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот маленький и простой код с использованием JQ библиотеки. Надеюсь поможет.

```
var distance = $('.basket').offset().top,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
           $('.basket').addClass('sticked')
        }
      if ( $window.scrollTop() <= distance ) {
           $('.basket').removeClass('sticked')
       }
```

**UPD** И добавляем соответственно сам класс sticked, который будет присваиваться в случае наступления события, например:

```
.sticked {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Иногда бывает, что ширина элемента после fixed начинает прыгать, тогда указываем в стиле .sticked параметр width:inherit, что поможет унаследовать ширину объекта после его фиксации.

Comment: тогда еще описание класса _sticked_ добавьте

Comment: второй `if` не нужен, достаточно `else` поставить

Answer (score 3):

#### Стандартное решение:

1. Подписываетесь на событие прокрутки
2. В обработчике события проверяете текущее смещение от верха:
   если смещение больше заранее рассчитанного значения,
   то ставить элементу с корзиной `position:fixed`,
   иначе ставить элементу с корзиной `position:relative`.

Либо выставлять соответствующие css-классы.

#### Ссылки по теме

[Обработчик onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)
[Добавление обработчика события](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
[Текущее смещение от верха страницы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)
[Условный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
[Выставление стилей](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Comment: не подскажите, где можно пример посмотреть?

Comment: @Николай, пример чего именно? кстати, без яваскрипта, на сколько я понимаю, это не сделать

Comment: @Николай, разобрались?

Comment: еще не получилось, но принцип понятен.